# How to know Application Installation is completed in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-applicationinfo

I want to create such a service which start when any new application is installing on android device. so how to know any application getting installed in android device, is there any Intent event is fired ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<receiver android:name="r1">

<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/> <data android:scheme="package"/>

</intent-filter> 

</receiver>
```

you can try this broadcast receiver....

also go through

```
"android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"
"android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"
```

might come in handy...